# Store Vuelidate validation state (v$) in external store (Pinia, Vuex)

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

Vuelidate 2 (aka "Next") is supposed to support using Vuelidate outside of Vue components. I'd like to store a global validation state (v$) in a Pinia store instead of in one or more components, using a mapped state property. One of the authors offered an [example](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/830) for doing this with the Composition API, where you pass a reactive state to `useVuelidate()`:

```
const formState = reactive({})
const rules = {}
const state = {
 someProperty: '',
 validations: useVuelidate(rules, formState)
}
export {
  state
}
```

I'm still using the Options API and Vue 2, but haven't been able to figure out to "translate" the above for the Options API. I've tried passing mapped state properties, but they get flagged as "undefined". E.g., something like this in my root component (note: you have to install the CompositionAPI module and use `setup` to use Vuelidate 2 in Vue 2):

```
setup: () => ({
v$: useVuelidate(this.mappedValidationRulesObject, this.mapped.StoreState)
})
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I don't think there's a straightforward translation. Options and composition are different apis that don't always have direct counterparts, and in case of Vuelidate, they are different plugin versions that work differently. As you can see, Vuelidate 0 can't be directly instantiated because a constructor isn't exposed https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/blob/v0.7.7/src/index.js#L576 . You can try to create `new Vue` instance (the closest counterpart to `reactive`) and access its $v